# Skip file in enumerate if it matches given text

Tags: python, loops, enumerate, skip

I have this code

```
for file in glob.glob("[!Skip]*.xlsm"):
....run various code
```

The argument is, if the file name starts with "Skip", do not apply this code on those files in the folder. It works beautifully. However sometime it skips file even if the name does not start with skip.

How come?

If i change the code to just "*.xlsm", it works on the file. So nothing is wrong with the file itself.

Comment: Do you have some more information, like : does your issue consistently apply to specific file, and if yes, what are the names?

Comment: @Pac0 No it doesn't apply to specific file. So I wonder if there's something wrong with my code? The code reads find file starting with "Skip" and without any spaces in a single word, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You use [!pattern] in wrong way.
Look at my little example.

```
import glob
import os
os.chdir('stof_names')
print(f"{glob.glob('*.txt')}")  # ['dont_Skip.txt', 'i.txt', 'Skip.txt', 'Skipme.txt', 'Spik_me.txt', 'S_me.txt']
print(f"{glob.glob('[!Skip]*.txt')}")  # ['dont_Skip.txt'] oops Where are my 'Spik_me.txt' and S_me.txt ans i.txt ?
# this happens because [!Skip] matches all symbols besides any of ['S','k','i','p']
# simplest solution, use 'filter' function
print(f"{list(filter(lambda x: not x.startswith('Skip'), glob.glob('*.txt')))}")
# ['dont_Skip.txt', 'i.txt', 'Spik_me.txt', 'S_me.txt']
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. Sorry I don't know how to get it to work? 


```for file in ({list(filter(lambda x: not x.startswith('Skip'), glob.glob('*.xlsm')))}):```

above returns TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'